Sushi and Sashimi
I love going to Japanese restaurants and enjoy eating all different types of sushi and sashimi. I would like to make sushi and sashimi at home. I think it would be a fun thing to do. What things would I need to buy to get started?

The "duplicate" question is about sushi... it doesn't say if there are any other considerations for sashimi

@Joe Sashimi is just raw fish, it doesn't need to be 'made'. You only need a trustworthy source of sufficiently fresh fish.

@quarague it's not always raw fish, although that's the most common in the US.  It can also be preserved or lightly cooked, and doesn't have to be fish
